# What software libraries are available to programmatically create photomosaics?

Tags: java, .net, windows, photo, photo-gallery

I'm looking for a library to programmatically create photomosaics of pictures of my kids... it's a toy side project.

I'm on Windows and would prefer a windows-based solution, be it Java or something else that I could run from the Java platform (even if it's .Net, that's cool, as long as I can execute it from CMD).

It needn't be free or open source

Do libraries like this exist?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not programmatic in any way, but it's the only mosaic tool I've used and it gives great results: http://www.andreaplanet.com/andreamosaic/

Answer (score 1):

@marc, check theses  .Net apps [`Mosaictor (from CodePlex)`](http://mosaictor.codeplex.com/) or this [`PhotoMosaic Generator`](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/31appsin31days/archive/2008/05/18/photomosaic-generator.aspx) with C# source code included. additionally you can see this great article [`Understanding Photomosaics`](http://www.drdobbs.com/184404848) from Dr. Dobbs